# reduce month in timestamp php

Tags: php, timestamp

I need a list which iterates through the months and always shows the last days like this

```
2015-04-30
2015-03-31
2015-02-28
...
```

My idea was to do this with the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php) method, where '1430344800' is the timestep according to 2015-04-30

```
$time_temp = 1430344800;
echo date('Y-m-t',$time_temp)."<br>";

$time_temp  =   strtotime("-1 month",$time_temp);
echo date('Y-m-t',$time_temp)."<br>";

$time_temp  =   strtotime("-1 month",$time_temp);
echo date('Y-m-t',$time_temp)."<br>";
```

but I just get

```
2015-04-30
2015-03-31
2015-03-31
```

replacing 'Y-m-t' by 'Y-m-d' gives

```
2015-04-30
2015-03-30
2015-03-02
```

Why is it not reducing the month properly and how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Iterate using the ___first___ of the month, because every month has at least 1 day, and then use `t` for your display

Comment: The string `-1 month` doesn't neccessarely get you the previous month

Comment: @adeneo what is it then doing?!

Comment: Try it and see -> `date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month", mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 31, 2015)))`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you that worked for me. I am still confused why it does not work when I don't take the first day of the month

Comment: It doesn't work because not every month has 31 days, or even 30 days, or even 29 days

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastDayOfMonth = time(); // depending on what you're trying to do, this could change. 
// For example, it could be = strtotime("+1 month");
for( $i = 0; $i < $numberOfMonthsToShow; $i++ ){
    $lastDayOfMonth = strtotime("last day of previous month", $lastDayOfMonth);
    echo date('Y-n-j', $lastDayOfMonth).'<br />';
}
```